# Removing an element from a structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, field

I have a structure:

```
 p=struct('exponent',{1,2,2,4},'coeff',{2,5,6,7})
```

I am trying to to remove the third element of the exponent field(2) and the `coeff` field(6), so that they **aren't** an empty space like this:

```
p=struct('exponent',{1,2,[],4},'coeff',{2,5,[],7})
```

but turns into a structure of length 3 like this

```
p=struct('exponent',{1,2,4},'coeff',{2,5,7})
```

I am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Easy way:

   ```
   p(3) = [];
   ```
2. Another approach, which allows more flexibility (for example you could remove third exponent and second coefficient, if that made sense):

   ```
   e = [p.exponent]; %// convert to vector
   e = num2cell(e([1:2 4:end])); %// remove third and convert to cell array
   c = [p.coeff];
   c = num2cell(c([1:2 4:end])); %// or remove any other than the third here
   p = struct('exponent',e,'coeff',c) %// recreate p
   ```